# Identity Server 4 JWT "access_token" is not valid for Identity Server Authorized endpoints

Tags: jwt, identityserver4

I have an Identity Server & API apps with ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials flow.

After getting "access_token" from RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync method I can use my [Authorized] endpoints in my API project, but can't access [Authorized] endpoints in my Identity Server app.

May be I'm missing something in AllowedScopes?

Identity Server's Starup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{

    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();

        var section = Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(section);
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
        loggerFactory.AddProvider(new FileLoggerProvider());
    }
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<IdentityDataContext>(optionsAction =>
            optionsAction.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopersConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDataContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential(filename: "tempkey.rsa")
            .AddInMemoryClients(IdentityConfig.GetClients("http://localhost:7017"))
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(IdentityConfig.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(IdentityConfig.GetApiResources())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();

        services.AddCors();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }

        RolesData.SeedRoles(app).Wait();
        app.UseCors(x =>
            x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:7017")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
        );

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Web Api Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient(typeof(IDataRepository<>), typeof(DataRepository<>));
        services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(optionsAction =>
            optionsAction.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopersConnection")));
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddAuthentication(
                JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:7777"; // Auth Server  
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false; // only for development  
                options.ApiName = "api"; // API Resource Id  
                options.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Jwt;

            });

        services.AddCors();
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCors(x =>
            x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:7017")
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
        );

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

IdentityConfig.cs:

```
public class IdentityConfig
{
    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients(string hostname) => new List<Client>
    {
        new Client
        {
            ClientId = "client",
            ClientName = "application",
            AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPasswordAndClientCredentials,
            AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
            AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
            ClientSecrets = {new Secret("secret".Sha256())},
            RequireConsent = false,
            RedirectUris           = { $"{hostname}/callback.html" },
            PostLogoutRedirectUris = { $"{hostname}/index.html" },
            AllowedCorsOrigins =     { hostname },
            AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
            AllowOfflineAccess = true,

            AllowedScopes =
            {
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                "api"
            }
        },
    };

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources() => new List<IdentityResource>
    {
        new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
        new IdentityResources.Email(),
        new IdentityResources.Profile(),
        new IdentityResource("role", new []{ JwtClaimTypes.Role })
    };

    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources() => new List<ApiResource>
    {
        new ApiResource("api")
        {
            UserClaims =
            {
                JwtClaimTypes.Email,
                JwtClaimTypes.Role,
                JwtClaimTypes.IdentityProvider,
                IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Getting Jwt access_token:

```
var disco = await DiscoveryClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:7777");
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "client", "secret");
var tokenResponse =
                    await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("username", "password", "openid api");

var access_token = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Could you post identityserver and api `Startup.cs`. Without code we can't understand problem.

Comment: @ademcaglin thanks for the response, updated

Comment: I couldn't see the problem. What is the error message you get? Check logs produced by api project, it might be helpful to understand problem.

Comment: @ademcaglin so with this token I'm able to access api Authorized endpoints, but when I'm trying to access with the same token Identity Server's Authorized endpoints I'm redirected to the login endpoint(so I suppose that my token is not valid for the Identity Server and it redirect's me to the login action)

Comment: I am not sure(i didn't test it) but you may need to configure identityserver like this. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/add_apis.html

Comment: @ademcaglin Is it possible that we should specify additional resource or scope to give possibility to use access_token for the identity server's endpoints? BTW: with adding services.AddAuthentication() in identity server's Startup.cs I can't even get token...

Comment: I tested it and worked as expected. Probably, you removed `AddIdentityServer`.

Comment: @ademcaglin As I understood from link that you send, this is about accessing identity server from the api, but I don't have problems with accessing Identity Server from the API!